# i cant install flutter because of error (69) telling me unable to get "pub upgrade"

Tags: flutter, dart, installation, terminal

so basically im trying to install flutter (flutter doctor) and i did have a error before (which is where it gets stuck on "resolving dependencies" but thats fixed now) and now its giving me another error "Got socket error trying to find package browser_launcher at https://pub.dev.
Error (69): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)" and im not really sure what to do either. i tried going onto the pub.dev website but it wont load, i dont know if its cause of slow connection (which is highly unlikey cause youtube and other websites works fine, but im not sure)

i haven't tried anything expect for trying to go to the website it links, which i cant go to.

Comment: Are you somewhere where unrestricted internet access is a problem? China for example?

Comment: sorry for late response, but no im not in china but i am in myanmar so do i need a vpn?

Comment: Well, you will need to reach https://pub.dev/, so if you figured out that you cannot (because it won't load in a browser for example) you will need a way around that. Since I don't know *why* you cannot reach it, I cannot say a VPN will be the solution, but it seems like a good guess.